# Unable to make JQuery function work

Tags: php, jquery

So, I have generated a table with a 'while' loop in php/mysql, and I want the user to be able to click an up arrow button with AJAX / JQuery and have it add +1 to an integer in the database **AND**  display that new value on the page.  I had this problem already solved, but by making changes elsewhere in my script somehow it has stopped working.  Let me show you what I have.

Here is php script, echoing the table.  I create an up arrow, then display the points (that I later want to add +1 to).

```
 <div id="new_UpArrow">


        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class = "new_upArrow"
        rowid="' . $row['item'] . '"><img src="../Img/new_upArrow.gif"/>
            </a> </div>';}

  ///////////POINTS/////////////
     echo ' <div class = "points" id="' . $row['item'] . '">'. $row['points'] . '</div>
```

Here is the JQuery.  I first send a GET statement to add +1 to the database, then I need it to display the new +1 value on the page for the user.

```
//upArrow
   $('.new_upArrow').click(function(){
   var row = $(this).attr('rowid');

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "upVote.php?id="+row,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    context: $('#'+row),
    success: function(result) {
    $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html()) + 1);
    },
    error: function(result){
        alert('Voting error, please try again.');
    }
    });
});
```

Again, this was working just fine a day ago, and now I can't get it to work again.  What is going on??

Thanks guys!!

edit:
After some further debugging here is where I am:

jQuery is pulling rowid from my php just fine as I am able to echo that variable.  However, even if I MANUALLY enter that ID into the 'context' part, the script fails.  **I am unable to focus jQuery on my 'points' div.**

Comment: any error on javascript console? the php gets called? if you alert(result) on the callback it works?

Comment: No errors, php successful, alert works

Comment: maybe context cant be a jquery object, but a DOM object. try setting it to `document.getElementById(row)`

Comment: Well I had this very script running perfectly before with 'context' the way it is now.  Either way, I tried putting document.getElementById(row) in, but unless my I am doing it wrong it is not letting me input that into the jquery syntax.

Comment: if you alert($(this).html()) it show the old number?

Comment: well.. than the problem is either the rowid attr or the div id

Comment: check if there´s no duplicate $row['item'] values

Comment: What you've got there is invalid markup. There is no `rowid` attribute for the `<a>` elements. If you're using custom attributes, use a data attribute like `data-rowid` and get the value in jQuery via `$object.data('rowid')`.

Comment: So, there are no other $row['item'] variables in my script.  All of my debugging has lead me to the following:  the rowid is valid, I can echo 'row' and it works just fine, this is why the GET php script works.  Where my code breaks down is the "Context" part.  Even if I MANUALLY enter the id for the 'points' into Context, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

(edit: OK, my first suggestion was very stupid, I didn't read the question properly, sorry about that)

Have you tried just using the selector inside the success function, instead of `$(this)` ? The `row` variable is in a closure, so you can just reuse that...

Comment: You know, I thought of this exact same thing driving into work today.  I won't be able to test it unit I get back home this afternoon, but I can't see why I won't work.  Of course, I can't see why its not working right now :), but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Nope, not working.  Even `alert($('#'+row).html());` comes back null. I don't get it.

Comment: Are you sure the HTML you have is valid? You could include firebug lite in your page and then run `$('#'+row).html()` from the console?

Comment: Well, I went back  to where I had it working, then moved FORWARD one step at a time to see where the code actually broke down.  Turns out it was with my MySQL query. Previously I was calling just ONE database, with the new code I am using a LEFT JOIN for the first time.  I still really don't know why I was unable to get it to work , but by changing the column name in one of my databases I have now been able to get it working the way I want. Ugh!  Well, thanks for all your help guys, but there really was no defined answer.  If anyone reading this has questions just message me.